# Toggle "Show scroll bars" radio buttons in Appearance section of System Settings via AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, accessibility, appearance

I need to write AppleScript that sets some value to Show scroll bars in new System Settings UI.

[Screenshot of what I want to change in result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipJw2.png)

Here's a code with which I did come up

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.Appearance-Settings.extension"
end tell

delay 0.1

tell application "System Events" to tell application process "System Settings"
    -- ...
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Accessibility Inspector application in which you can view the hierarchy of elements in any app. With its help, I wrote the working script:

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.Appearance-Settings.extension"
end tell

delay 0.1

tell application "System Events" to tell application process "System Settings"
    set frontmost to true
    tell window 1
        tell group 1
            tell splitter group 1
                tell group 2
                    tell group 1
                        tell scroll area 1
                            tell group 2
                                tell radio group 1
                                    set targetUIElement to a reference to radio button 1
                                    if targetUIElement exists then
                                        click targetUIElement
                                    end if
                                end tell
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        tell button 1 to click
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Why do you want users to show or not show scrollbars

Comment: @react_or_angluar The answer is simple. During development, it's important to have scroll bars turned on. Automatically hiding scroll bars in macOS is more pleasant, though, but it takes a long time to change scroll bar visibility manually. So, I wanted to automate this process.